# How to change column in matrix according to another column

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have such matrix:

```
   Property     Group  Numb
1      rule     panic    13
2      rule      calm    70
3      mild     panic    21
4      mild      calm    59
5     chaos     panic    46
6     chaos      calm    43
```

I want to change the third column: each value is to be divided by the sum of numbers in this column with corresponding group.

For example, first row should be like that:

`1      rule     panic    13/(13+21+46`)

We divide the value by sum of `Numbs` for entries with `Group = panic`.
I know the brute force of doing it, but would you help me with an elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    mutate(Numb = Numb/sum(Numb))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Numb1:= Numb/sum(Numb) , Group][]
```

Or using `base R`

```
df1$Numb <- with(df1, ave(Numb, Group, FUN=function(x) x/sum(x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
 Property     Group  Numb
1      rule     panic    13
2      rule      calm    70
3      mild     panic    21
4      mild      calm    59
5     chaos     panic    46
6     chaos      calm    43")
df$Numb/ave(df$Numb, df$Group, FUN="sum")
# [1] 0.1625000 0.4069767 0.2625000 0.3430233 0.5750000 0.2500000
```